# Streamlining Parameter Passing

Tags: c++, methods, parameters, class-design, code-complete

I am reading through *[Code Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Complete)* and had a question about "Streamlining parameter passing". The author says that if you are passing a parameter among several routines, that might indicate a need to factor those routines into a class that share the parameter as class data.

Does this mean that if I have several separate class that use the same data I should create one new class that uses that data and then inherit to make new classes?

Or

Does this mean that if I have a bunch of loose routines in my program I should go ahead and put them into a class and get the benefits of encapsulation, etc.

Comment: not everybody has to book at hand, thus it would be good, if you could include an exact quote in the question.

Comment: There's a "might" in the text you're referring to, and it doesn't imply that you *should* do anything in particular, except use your own good judgement to determine whether perhaps your code could benefit from being restructured. Applying this idea *might* also lead to a worse mess than you started with.

Answer (score 2):

The latter. It looks like they're talking about a case like this:

```
void function_1(std::string& my_data);
void function_2(std::string& my_data);

void main() {
    std::string my_data = "SomeString";
    function_1(my_data);
    function_2(my_data);
}
```

Which could be changed to:

```
class MyClass {
    std::string my_data;
public:
    MyClass(const std::string& str) : my_data(str) {}
    void function_1();
    void function_2();
}

void main() {
    MyClass obj("SomeString");
    obj.function_1();
    obj.function_2();
}
```

Where `function_1` and `function_2` use the `my_data` field, instead of having to be passed the string every time.

Comment: So it is about keeping a piece of data private and within the class instead of passing it between classes.
Thankn you for the code example.

Comment: Well, this was a simple example, so the readability improvement is not that big. But if we have, say, 20 variables that we have to pass to each function, it's a lot cleaner to pass them just once to a constructor. That's the main point they seem to be going at. The encapsulation is nice for other reasons though.